# Is there narrow characters version of iswctype() function?

Tags: c++, c, posix, locale

Is there any kind of narrow character function like there is `iswctype()` for wide characters?

**UPDATE**

I did not realize there was `std::regex_traits::isctype()`, otherwise I would have made the question explain the situation better:

I am actually implementing `std::ctype<char>` facet itself so I cannot use `std::regex_traits::isctype()` as itself depends on `std::ctype<char>::is()`.

Please suggest POSIX or C99 function instead.

Comment: If you're implementing `std::ctype`, how would C or POSIX functions help?

Comment: int isctype (int c) {return c >= 0 && (unsigned)(c+1) <= 256;}

Comment: @Cubbi: The implementation can be limited to POSIX platforms.

Comment: @wilx Are you building a `std::ctype` around the POSIX `newlocale()` and want to support extended classifications such as (to use POSIX example) isvowel?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain the problem you are trying to solve, else this is an XY question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I am implementing `std::ctype<char>::is()`. How is that XY problem?

Comment: @wilx: Here is a handy link explaining what the XY problem is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. You're telling us what you're trying to do to attain some goal, and not what your goal is.

Comment: @wilx: Thank you for your well-informed and professional follow-up comment. It's always a pleasure.

Comment: Incidentally, how can your `ctype::is` classify a character against a locale-specific classification if it takes `ctype_base::mask` as an argument? There is no `std::ctype_base::vowel` or `std::ctype_base::kanji`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01), for the extended character classes,

> The *charclass-name* can be used as the property argument to the `wctype()` function, in regular expression and shell pattern-matching bracket expressions, and by the `tr` command.

and [the POSIX regex page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), correspondingly, says

> In addition, character class expressions of the form:
>
> `[:name:]`
>
> are recognized in those locales where the name keyword has been given a *charclass* definition in the `LC_CTYPE` category.

So, to reach an extended classification in a narrow-character locale, the only POSIX-compliant way appears to be the POSIX regex class, much like the only way to get to it in C++ is the already-mentioned `std::regex_traits::isctype`.

Perhaps you're better off reaching into platform-specific APIs, in terms of which these functions are implemented (where accessible).

PS: Perhaps the more practical approach is to  just call `btowc` and `iswctype`. A locale that classifies a narrow char and its widened form differently is questionable to say the least.

Comment: "btowc and iswctype" -- I have thought about that before asking. I wanted to know whether there was something more direct. If this is the only way to do this, I guess I will use it then.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method provided by the Standard Regular Expression library named [`std::regex_traits::isctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_traits/isctype). Note that it uses `std::regex_traits` which is a C++11 construct.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use that, please see my question update.

Comment: @wilx I don't know of any other function but it shouldn't be hard to implement the table lookup your self.

Comment: How would that play with different 8 bit character sets?

Comment: @wilx I'm definitely not familiar with this kind of stuff so I wouldn't know. Sorry! :(

Answer (score -3):

They are functions declared in header `<ctype.h>` in C or `<cctype>` in C++ including isdigit, isalpha and so on.

Comment: Your answer is to a different question, it seems.

Comment: @wilx I do not think so. For example iswctype(wc, wctype("alnum")) // iswalnum(wc)

Comment: `iswctype` was introduced by C95 to support iskanji, ishanja, and other extended classifications not already covered by the existing C90 isxxx functions.